# Deleted comments break a conversation

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I [answered a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145580/differential-pair-impedance-calculation/145586#145586) and then continued to clarify things for the asker, both by editing my answer and by answering directly in the comments.

Now the original asker has deleted his questions, perhaps as he learned a bit more, thinking they looked like stupid questions, so the conversation is broken and my comments don't make much sense. They were actually good questions and cast light on the problem, the conversation might have been useful to a later reader.

So my question is, should I now go back and re-format my comments to make them general clarifications, or delete them and embellish my answer, or just leave them?

Comment: Patrick has already posted a good answer, but just FYI, this question would probably have been better suited for the [local meta site for electronics.SE](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/). Different SE communities do have somewhat different approaches to comments -- some are *very* strict about enforcing the "comments are temporary" policy, which others are more inclined to just leave them be as long as they're not causing any active harm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are not meant to stay forever. If there is relevant information in your  comments regarding your answer, just add it to the answer.

If it was just helpful to OP, let it out.

If it is not related to the actual question, but you think it might help future readers, you could opt to create a new question / answer pair for that specific part. Make sure your upgraded comment is decent enough to be an answer.